# Change directory to startup folder

Tags: windows, vbscript

This folder can be opened by typing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then `Shell:startup`.

I want to make a script change directory to this folder. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The startup folder can be determined via the [`SpecialFolders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property of the `WshShell` object. Changing the current directory is done via the [`CurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc5edzd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.CurrentDirectory = sh.SpecialFolders("Startup")
```